# how to sort an ms word document heading by tab columns

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I sort a Word document heading by a tab column?
(where a column is the text on a heading after two tabs)

That is, in my doc, in outline view, each heading begins with 'n'. (where n is an integer), after heading text there are two tabs, and then another number 'm'.

I used to be able to sort by "n" at beginning heading, or by 'm' after two tabs (the tab column).
  But I don't remember how.  (many years ago).  But I remember I could do it, and I need to now.

Comment: I am having difficulty envisaging this. Could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Select your text, eg.

```
Aa  bb  dd
Dd  cc  mm
Bb  dd  bb
Cc  kk  ll
```

In menu bar, in paragraph span, you will see an icon having AZ-Dowarrow. Click on that, it opens options where you can define the field separator, that is tab by default, and other things, and then you can define sorting order say, Field-1/2/3, Ascending/ Descending, so on.